# Restrict category choice in dropdown menu?

Tags: categories

**Hmmm... maybe trickier than I hoped? If this is simply impossible then please do let me know :-)** Question Refinement:How can I adapt the include section of this code to use category names instead of id's? Thanks

```
$dropdown = wp_dropdown_categories( array(
'include' => '58, 3',
    'name' => 'category_id[]',
    'hide_empty' => false,
    'echo' => false,
) );
```

---

I recently started using this code to force users of a multisite to select a category from a dropdown menu before creating a new post.

Can anyone help me restrict the category options to just a few specific categories eg. news / products? Even just not displaying sub-categories would be helpful. Thanks

UPDATE: I found adding this line I was able to restrict the choice to just 2 categories:

```
 'include' => '58, 3',
```

But how can I make this work with cat names / text instead of id numbers as it's for a multisite & I don't have control over cat id's when new sites are created????

CODE:

```
add_filter( 'load-post-new.php', 'wpse14403_load_post_new' );
function wpse14403_load_post_new()
{
$post_type = 'post';
if ( isset( $_REQUEST['post_type'] ) ) {
    $post_type = $_REQUEST['post_type'];
}

// Only do this for posts
if ( 'post' != $post_type ) {
    return;
}

if ( array_key_exists( 'category_id', $_REQUEST ) ) {
    add_action( 'wp_insert_post', 'wpse14403_wp_insert_post' );
    return;
}

// Show intermediate screen
extract( $GLOBALS );
$post_type_object = get_post_type_object( $post_type );
$title = $post_type_object->labels->add_new_item;

include( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/admin-header.php' );

$dropdown = wp_dropdown_categories( array(
    'name' => 'category_id[]',
    'hide_empty' => false,
    'echo' => false,
) );

$category_label = __( 'Category:' );
$continue_label = __( 'Continue' );
echo <<<HTML
<div class="wrap">
<h2>{$title}</h2>

<form method="get">
    <table class="form-table">
        <tbody>
            <tr valign="top">
                <th scope="row">{$category_label}</th>
                <td>{$dropdown}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <th><input name="continue" type="submit" class="button-primary" value="{$continue_label}" /></th>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <input type="hidden" name="post_type" value="{$post_type}" />
</form>
</div>
HTML;
include( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/admin-footer.php' );
exit();
}

// This function will only be called when creating an empty post,
// via `get_default_post_to_edit()`, called in post-new.php
function wpse14403_wp_insert_post( $post_id )
{
wp_set_post_categories( $post_id, $_REQUEST['category_id'] );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well after thinking about this some more, I've realised that it was a bit of a dumb question to ask... **My problem is actually being able to pre-define categories in themes for new subsites of my mulitiste.**

I've got around this by using a premium plugin which allows me to offer blog templates / themes with a few predefined categories and some dummy content. This means that I already know the category id's when a new subsite is created.

Now new users can choose any of my themes, and most of them will have an e-shop option which will have the dropdown "product" category pre-installed etc.

Good grief, the lengths I'm going to to try and simplify the whole wp cms :-)

If anyone's interested I'll post a link to the full project here sometime soon (I hope).